# Scala generic type alias in trait - Wrong number of type arguments

Tags: scala, generics, types

I thought the following code would work for sure, but it reports the error "Wrong number of type arguments. Expected: 2, actual: 1"

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Cache[K] = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[K, Option[Things]]
}
abstract class MyImpl[T] extends MyTrait[T] {
  val cache = new Cache[String]
}
```

I've made it work by changing it to:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Key
  type Cache = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Key, Option[Things]]
}
abstract class MyImpl[T] extends MyTrait[T] {
  type Key = String
  val cache = new Cache
}
```

But what am i misunderstanding about scalas type system? Why can't i create different Cache[T] implementations in 'MyImpl'. E.g. why can't i create a Cache[String] and Cache[Int] in MyImpl?

And finally, what is the best way to achieve this type of structure in Scala?

Comment: I've succesfully compiled your original code (scala 2.11.5)

Comment: You know what, I'm an idiot. I trusted intellij error instead of trying scalac. It does compile. Ha! If you put that as an answer i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it said in my comment, the code does compile (with scalac):

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Cache[K] = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[K, Option[Things]]
}
abstract class MyImpl[T] extends MyTrait[T] {
  val cache = new Cache[String]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about type arguments as if they were function arguments. Here you have 2 things that vary, the T's contained in the Seq and the K used as a key for the cache.
For a function, you would write: `myTraitFactory(t, k)`
For type arguments, you write `MyTrait[T, K]`

That gives us:

```
trait MyTrait[K, T] {
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Cache = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[K, Option[Things]]
}
abstract class MyImpl[K, T] extends MyTrait[K, T] {
  val cache = new Cache
}
class MyCache extends MyImpl[String, Cacheable]
```

You don't really need to write Cache[K] as K is already defined as a parameter in the type arguments of the class.
MyImpl keeps the 2 types K and T unknown, while MyCache fixes those types to concrete classes and is not abstract anymore.

Instead of making explicit the type parameters, you can declare them as you did with `Key` in the trait/class body, and leave them abstract until you fix their value in a subclass or sub-trait.

```
trait MyTrait {
  type T
  type Key
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Cache = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Key, Option[Things]]
}
abstract class MyImpl extends MyTrait {
  type Key = String
  val cache = new Cache // using Strings as keys
}
class MyCache extends MyImpl {
  type T = Cacheable
}
```

Your cache probably don't need to store keys associated with no values (None), otherwise cache.get would return Option[Option[Seq[T]]] which doesn't look easy to work with, so finally for a cache I would write:

```
trait MyTrait[K, T] {
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Cache = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Key, Things]
}
```

Comment: I'm caching whether something exists or not. If I get Some(None) out of the Cache then that means it doesnt exist. I get None from the Cache then it means I should go get it. And I didn't want K to be the same for child classes, I only wanted the value of the Cache to be fixed for sub classes. It was a contrived example, sorry if it was misleading. Thanks for your answer, but as dk14 mentioned, there is nothing wrong with my original code.

Comment: Try this in the Scala console:

    scala> val c = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
    c: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map()

    scala> c.get("x")
    res0: Option[Int] = None

If the element doesn't exist in the map, it already returns None

Comment: You're missing the point. i know Map.get gives me an option. There are three cases I need to be able to check that Option alone does not give me. #1 Does not exist in Cache and has not been checked (None). #2 Exists in cache but does not exist (Some(None)). #3 Exists in cache and does exist (Some(_)). Cache is a really bad name for what i'm doing lol. It was sample code

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with Intellij IDEA. The below code does compile:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  type Things = Seq[T]
  type Cache[K] = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[K, Option[Things]]
}
abstract class MyImpl[T] extends MyTrait[T] {
  val cache = new Cache[String]
}
```